# A function prints the value but It's not printed on another function when returned

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get the near by location using firebase query and it goes well. This the function that gets the nearby location.

```
Future<List<DocumentSnapshot>> nearbyLocations() async {
    CollectionReference collectionRefer =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('locations');
    double radius = 10;
    String field = 'position';
    List<DocumentSnapshot> docList;
    GeoFirePoint center = await getCurrentLocation();
    // print(center);
    Stream<List<DocumentSnapshot>> stream = geo
        .collection(collectionRef: collectionRefer)
        .within(center: center, radius: radius, field: field, strictMode: true);
    stream.listen((List<DocumentSnapshot> documentList) {
      if (documentList.length > 0) {
        print(documentList[0].data());
        docList = documentList;
      } else {
        return {};
      }
    });
  }
```

I know that the query will return only one data. So, I printed on the first value in the above function.
The problem arises when the documentList is returned.

```
loadData() async {
    documentList =
        await GeoLocator().nearbyLocations();
  }
```

When I call this above function, It prints null. But When I tried to print in the `nearbyLocations()` It print the data. But not when I Call `loadData()`. I'm going to use this returned data in listview.

Comment: This seems like an async issue. Your `nearbyLocations()` is an async method. Either you need to make you `loadData()` async or add a callback to  `nearbyLocations()`  using `then((value){ // print value here});`

Comment: @BurhanuddinRashid I forgot to update my code. I also used async to `loadData()` and still after `then` It prints null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing `await`, streams and `then`. This is probably too much to keep in mind at the same time.

Focus on one method at first. I suggest `async`/`await` since that is the easiest.

Your nearbyLocations method does not return anything. You did not define a type and it does not have a return statement either. Yet, you seem to expect it to return a `Future<>` with a specified type.

Make sure you crank up your warnings and use the [pedantic](https://pub.dev/packages/pedantic) package to have your analyzer notify you when you forget those things.

When you actually declare your method fully, your warnings should show you that you have no return in your method.

---

I don't have a compiler here or packages to include, but this seems to be what you really want:

```
Future<List<DocumentSnapshot>> nearbyLocations() async {
    final collectionRefer = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('locations');
    final radius = 10.0;
    final field = 'position';
    final center = await getCurrentLocation();

    final stream = geo
        .collection(collectionRef: collectionRefer)
        .within(center: center, radius: radius, field: field, strictMode: true);

    return stream.first;
  }
```

Comment: As you said I made some alterations to my code but still the `nearbyLocations()` function returns null. Please help me sort this out!

Comment: Well, your nearbyLocations method still has no return statement. Your two return statements belong to the anonymous method used in the stream listener. Why is it a stream in the first place? Shouldn't it be a Future, because you only want a single result set?

Comment: If multiple shops are found near me all the shops should be returned so I used stream. I'll try adding return statements correctly

Comment: Do you want this to be a continuous stream while your location changes or do you want this to be a snapshot of the data at the current location?

Comment: Snapshot of the data at current location. As you said I placed a return statement in nearbyLocation function but no change in output.

Comment: Yeah! It worked and you made a magic with just a line can you explain me the mistakes I made and what you have done in answer section? Please it can help me.

Comment: Well, a `Stream` is a continuous stream of results. For example live updates while you move around. You don't want that. You only want the first result set of that stream. So you can get it as a `Future` with the `first` getter, which is exactly what you need. You had two `return` statements, but they did not actually return from your own method, just from the anonymous method you registered with the stream.